# Help with this query dealing with aggregates

Tags: mysql

I have a database that stores information about artists, bands and albums and I'm trying to select the band names and album titles for bands with more than 1 album.

```
band_id, name,            year_formed
1,       blink182,        1990
2,       fall out boy,    1997
3,       u2,              1982
4,       coldplay,        1990
5,       zach brown band, 2002
```

and album

```
album_id, title,                          band_id
1,        take off your pants and jacket, 1
2,        stars,                          3
3,        fbgm,                           3
4,        reach,                          3
5,        yup,                            4
```

This doesn't seem too hard of a problem but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.
The problem seems to be with getting both the album title and band name from the select statement.

```
SELECT b.name, alb.title
FROM band as b, album as alb
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM album as al WHERE b.bid = alb.bid)
```

Returns the all band names and their album titles. My guess is to have the subquery handle finding the bands with more than one album but I just am at a complete loss for how to do this. Subqueries have been throwing me for a loop in general, so any nice description of how they work conceptually would be appreciated.

Comment: The tables' data have `band_id` but the code has `bid`. Which is the actual column name?

Answer (score 0):

First your query is missing a join on the two tables involved. After that, it can be slightly altered to get you the albums of bands with more than one album, like this:

```
SELECT b.name, alb.title                     -- show me all bands 
FROM band AS b                               -- and their albums
  JOIN album AS alb                          
    ON alb.band_id = b.band_id    
WHERE EXISTS                                 -- where exists at least one
      ( SELECT *    
        FROM album AS al                     -- other album
        WHERE al.band_id = alb.band_id       -- of the same band
          AND al.album_id <> alb.album_id    -- (this ensures the "other")
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine which bands that have more than 1 album you can do something like:

```
SELECT b.bid 
FROM band as b
JOIN album as a
   ON b.bid = a.bid
GROUP BY b.bid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Since band_name and year_formed is likely to be f.d. of bid:

```
SELECT b.bid, max(b.name), max(b.year_formed) 
FROM band as b
JOIN album as a
   ON b.bid = a.bid
GROUP BY b.bid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```